# Return a set of values from a map

Tags: java, generics, collections, dictionary

I have a map `HashMap <Integer,Employee> map= new HashMap<Integer,Employee>();` The class `Employee` has an int attribute `int empid;` which will serve as key to the map.

My method is

```
public Set<Employee> listAllEmployees()
{
      return map.values();                //This returns a collection,I need a set
}
```

How to get set of employees from this method?

Comment: Can you clarify in what way you want the employees you get to be different than the other employees? Are you asking something like a range of IDs, a set of random IDs? etc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a new `HashSet` with `map.values()`

```
public Set<Employee> listAllEmployees()
{
      return  new HashSet<Employee>(map.values());                
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 by Stream API you can use this method

```
public Set<Employee> listAllEmployees(Map<Integer,Employee> map){
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Upd.: This code performs the task but is some kind of overcoding. Just KISS and do it as in answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075053/4609353

Answer (score 1):

Some other options.

You can still use the Collection Interface to do all possible set operations.
Iteration, clear etc etc. (Note that the Collection returned by values() is an unmodifiable collection)

Use map.values().toArray() method and return an array.